# Javascript date parsing YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS T

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a string to date which comes in below format

`2012-05-23 12:12:00-05:00`

`Date.parse("2012-05-23 12:12:00-05:00")`

It is working fine with chorme but not in Firefox and IE. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js's date parsing:

```
var date = moment("2012-05-23 12:12:00-05:00");
```

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous (less relevant) answer. This function should suit your purposes much better.

The key strategy is to get an absolute representation of your time without the time zone, and then adjust it backward or forward based on the specified timezone. What it spits out is a `Date` object in your browser's local time zone, but it will represent exactly the same moment in time as the string does.

Also, the format you specified isn't quite to spec, so the regex I wrote accepts your version as well as ISO8601.

```
Date.createFromString = function (string) {
    'use strict';
    var pattern = /^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)[ T](\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)([+-Z])(\d\d):(\d\d)$/;
    var matches = pattern.exec(string);
    if (!matches) {
        throw new Error("Invalid string: " + string);
    }
    var year = matches[1];
    var month = matches[2] - 1;   // month counts from zero
    var day = matches[3];
    var hour = matches[4];
    var minute = matches[5];
    var second = matches[6];
    var zoneType = matches[7];
    var zoneHour = matches[8] || 0;
    var zoneMinute = matches[9] || 0;

    // Date.UTC() returns milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    var absoluteMs = Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    var ms;
    if (zoneType === 'Z') {
        // UTC time requested. No adjustment necessary.
        ms = absoluteMs;
    } else if (zoneType === '+') {
        // Adjust UTC time by timezone offset
        ms = absoluteMs - (zoneHour * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (zoneMinute * 60 * 1000);
    } else if (zoneType === '-') {
        // Adjust UTC time by timezone offset
        ms = absoluteMs + (zoneHour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (zoneMinute * 60 * 1000);
    }
    return new Date(ms);
};
```